# ConnectionStrings Current Language=Portuguese not working with (LocalDB)\v11.0

Tags: connection-string, localdb

I use this connection string  with SQLExpress and I can get the error messages in portuguese.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AssociGestorDb"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;
                           Trusted_Connection=true;
                           Current Language=Portuguese;
                           Database=AssociGestorDb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I try to do the same with (LocalDB)\v11.0 but do not work.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AssociGestorDb" 
        connectionString="Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                          Database=AssociGestorDb;
                          Integrated Security=True;
                          Current Language=Portuguese;
                          Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What is the proper way to get the error messages in portuguese using (LocalDB)\v11.0?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Portuguese version of LocalDB? Some errors are processed before the connection string is fully parsed, and I think those will default to the language installed LocalDB binaries were built for.

Comment: No, i have not installed the Portuguese version of LocalDB neither SQLExpress. I have test with a `Violation of PRIMARY KEY.... Cannot insert duplicate key in ...` error. Using SQLExpress the error is shown in portuguese.

Comment: Then I don't know, I believe this error is supposed to be properly localized using session locale.